# How do I display icons in VIM

Tags: vim, icons, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm  looking to set up vim to display icons in my NerdTree pane.

I have it set as:

```
let g:NERDTreeIndicatorMapCustom = {                                                                                                    
                        \ "Modified"  : "✹",                                                                                            
                        \ "Staged"    : "✚",                                                                                            
                        \ "Untracked" : "✭",                                                                                            
                        \ "Renamed"   : "➜",                                                                                            
                        \ "Unmerged"  : "═",                                                                                            
                        \ "Deleted"   : "✖",                                                                                            
                        \ "Dirty"     : "✗",                                                                                            
                        \ "Clean"     : "✔",                                                                                            
                        \ 'Ignored'   : '☒',                                                                                            
                        \ "Unknown"   : "?"
```

It would be similar to how VSCode is set.
Which display correctly here but not in my terminal it just has `[x]`.

Is there a setting I can change?

I'm trying to set it up so that each file type has its own icon and git status for the file is visually shown.

I ended up installing a nerd font and airline now everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [vim-devicons](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons)

Comment: Ok, I have  that plugin is there anything special I need to do to it. Normally I just install it do I need the full nerd font directory

Comment: Of course, you have to follow its recommendations, because there are some patched fonts to enable it. At least to me, these two steps were enough.

Comment: Ok, I'll go through the recommendations again